how to select the grandparent selector of a class CSS
I have this image :

what I'm trying to do is to apply css to the yellow class (st-emotion-cache-1jicfl2) based on his child st-key-image-container in green
because I have two pages which contains the same css selector (st-emotion-cache-1jicfl2) the only way to apply css to it is to select his unique child ex :st-key-image-container
i have tried this :
.st-emotion-cache-1jicfl2:has(.st-key-image-container){
width: 100%;
padding:0px !important; 
min-width: auto;
max-width: initial;

 }

but it didnt work. could you help please ?

Your code should work unless there is other more specific CSS somewhere.
Perhaps there is something else going on. Try my code to see if at least it changes color. Right-click and inspect to see what the values are in the computed CSS


.st-emotion-cache-1jicfl2:has(.st-key-image-container) {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0px !important;
  min-width: auto;
  max-width: initial;
  background-color: red;
  display:flex;
}

.st-key-image-container {
  background-color: yellow; margin-top: 50px;
}
<div class="st-emotion-cache-1jicfl2">Does not have an image container</div>
<div class="st-emotion-cache-1jicfl2">DOES have an image container
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <div class="st-key-image-container">Image container</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="st-emotion-cache-1jicfl2">Does not have an image container</div>




hi, thanks but  want to apply the css to st-emotion-cache-1jicfl2 not st-key-image-container

The class IS applied to the parent container. Look again

thanks for your time and effort..but what should be in yellow is this :No image container because it is the parent

I assume you have several st-emotion-cache-1jicfl2 but you want to target only the ones with an image container nested in them. I made three st-emotion-cache-1jicfl2 and added the image container to the middle one to prove that regardless of how many st-emotion-cache-1jicfl2 containers you had, only the one(s) with image container were targeted

but this is what i tried before..but it did not impact st-emotion-cache-1jicfl2 in the screenshot above..i dont know why

i will mark it as correct andwset event if does not work for me..I have no idea why

But have a look to see why not. Perhaps there is something else going on. Try my code to see if at least it changes color. Right-click and inspect to see what the values are in the   computed CSS

Perhaps use .stMainBlockContainer in case the 1jicfl2  is different every time you load the page
